# How to hide console window in Mac OS (gcc compiler)?

Tags: c++, macos, console, hide

I write an application with Code::Blocks IDE in Mac OS (C++ application).

CodeBlocks uses gcc to compile the source code.

When I double click on the output of the project (executable binary file), my application executes correctly but a console application shown. My application is a background application without any reading or writing to console, and I add it to startup items. I don't want when I logon, a balnk console (of my application) shown. I want to hide the console window.

How to hide console window in Mac OS with gcc compiler?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are developing is a daemon (background process that is launched when a user account is logged on, or system is launched).  OS X uses [launchd and launchctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) to manage daemons, so you'll need to set up the proper plist entry in either the /System/Library/LaunchAgents (to launch during system boot) or ~/Library/LaunchAgents (to launch when a user logs in) directory, and register it with launchctl.