# How to hide terminal window in mac osx?

Tags: c++, macos

I have a multi platform application that runs on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac. It is compiled with g++ on all platforms.

For windows, I created an installer and got rid of the terminal window by adding the linker flag:

```
-Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

I am looking for a similar option on Mac. How do I get rid of the console window when I open the executable from GUI?

This question is similar to [How to hide console window in Mac OS (gcc compiler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794340/how-to-hide-console-window-in-mac-os-gcc-compiler), except that my app is no daemon.

Thanks.

Comment: How is your application being launched?  Typically on Mac if the application is launched by double-clicking on its icon, no Terminal window appears (and thus no Terminal window needs to be hidden).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, except if the program is just a Unix executable file, double-clicking on its icon will launch Terminal and issue its path as a command (thus running it). What Matferib should do is build an application bundle around his executable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your description, you're building what is a unix-style executable.  On OS X, those will always launch inside of a terminal window.  The choices that you have on OS X are:

- Run as a daemon as described in the above-linked post
- Run in Terminal as a unix executable
- Create a minimal OS X application wrapper and run as an OS X Application

In most cases, you can create a wrapper for a unix-style executable by creating the appropriate *Bundle* using the instructions from [Apple's Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) (skip over the iOS stuff and look at the Mac bundle information).

The basic directory structure is:

```
MyApp.app/
  Contents/
    Info.plist
  MacOS/
    executable
  Resources/
    MyApp.icns
```

Your unmodified executable can go in the `MacOS` directory, and you'll need to set up the following keys in the `Info.plist` using a plist editing tool or editor:

- `CFBundleIdentifier` - the id of your app in reverse-dns notation (`com.mycompany.myapp`)
- `CFBundleDisplayName` - the name of your app in human-readable form (`MyApp`)
- `CFBundleName` - the short name of the app (usually the same as your app and executable name)
- `CFBundleVersion` - your version # in X.Y[.Z] form
- `CFBundlePackageType` - the package type, which should be `APPL` for applications
- `CFBundleExecutable` - the name of your executable
- `CFBundleSignature` - old-school Apple signature (4 character code that should theoretically be registered with apple)

A minimal plist would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>a.out</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>FOOZ</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(The above example uses `a.out` as the executable, which would be located in `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/a.out`)

The icon resources can be left out if you don't care about the icon, and the default application icon will be used.

Comment: After investigating a lot, it seems this is the only way. For my application, things get more complicated because it saves files to one of its internal folders. So I guess Ill have to create a wrapper to my  file libraries and save it somewhere else in case of a mac. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's a bit of a problem on a Mac.  Generally, you need to look at saving in the user's `~/Library/Application Support/` folder to comply with normal Mac behavior.