# How to hide/quit terminal while program is still running in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm doing my project and I need to log keystrokes system wide in macOS. So, I turned over to GitHub and found [Swift-Keylogger](https://github.com/SkrewEverything/Swift-Keylogger). The only problem is I can't quit the Terminal while the program is still running.

Is there any way to not to run this in terminal or closing the terminal window instead of creating a mac app like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861914/how-to-hide-terminal-window-in-mac-osx).

Note: There are some mac app style executables in github but they are not providing the output I want and some need additional permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running the executable like `./Keylogger` use `nohup ./Keylogger &`.

You can quit the Terminal after executing the command.

To kill the Keylogger, run `ps -e | grep "Keylogger"` to get pid and `kill -9 pid`.

P.S. I thought of adding it as well as running at startup but I'm too lazy to update the repository.

Comment: Can you please add the automatically run at startup feature? And thank you. Great Work!